# PL/SQL for returning all the output set from the FOR loop with an input array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to pass inputs from an array using a for loop. Finally, I want to return all the outputs from each iteration altogether.
But with this query it just returns the dataset from very last call and overrides the results for the other inputs from the array.

Example: Input: po_array_in :=(123,789, 456)
So it will just return the output from the last input '456' and overrides the results from all other inputs.

Is their any way to get all the outputs for each input altogether? Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Test.return_array_test1
AS
   ex_custom   EXCEPTION;



   TYPE return_array_test1 IS RECORD
   (
      name1 VARCHAR2 (100),
      address1 VARCHAR2 (100),
      city VARCHAR2 (100),
      state_code VARCHAR2 (100),
      zip VARCHAR2 (100),
      order_type VARCHAR2 (100) ,
      po VARCHAR2 (100)
   );

    TYPE return_array_test_TBL IS TABLE OF return_array_test1
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


   PROCEDURE array_test_input  (
      po_array_in IN num_array,
      x_comp_rec  OUT return_array_test_TBL
             );
END return_array_test1;
/
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Test.return_array_test1
AS

 PROCEDURE array_test_input  (
      po_array_in IN num_array,
      x_comp_rec  OUT return_array_test_TBL
             )IS

BEGIN             

    FOR i IN 1 .. po_array_in.count
   LOOP

    select b.name,b.address1,b.city,b.state_code,b.zip,a.order_type,a.po bulk collect into x_comp_rec from headers a,customers b
   where a.po =  po_array_in(i) and decode(a.deliver_to_site_use_id,null,a.ship_to_site_use_id,a.deliver_to_site_use_id) = b.site_use_id(+) 
   and '123456' in (substr(a.contract_dealer,1,8),substr(a.install_dealer,1,8),substr(a.ordertaking_dealer,1,8));

     END LOOP;

END array_test_input;

END   return_array_test1;
/
```

Comment: Where are how is `num_array` defined?

Comment: create type num_array as table of varchar2(200);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over your array; you can use the collection directly and query all of its values at once (depending on how it was defined), with `member of` if `num_array` is a schema-level SQL type:

```
...
BEGIN

  select b.name, b.address1, b.city, b.state_code, b.zip, a.order_type,a.po
  bulk collect into x_comp_rec
  from headers a
  left join customers b
  on b.site_use_id = coalesce(a.deliver_to_site_use_id, a.ship_to_site_use_id)
  where a.po member of po_array_in
  and '123456' in (substr(a.contract_dealer,1,8), substr(a.install_dealer,1,8),
    substr(a.ordertaking_dealer,1,8));

END array_test_input;
```

or with a table collection expression if `num_array` is a schema-level SQL type or, in 12c, is a PL/SQL type:

```
...
BEGIN
  select b.name, b.address1, b.city, b.state_code, b.zip, a.order_type,a.po
  bulk collect into x_comp_rec
  from table(po_array_in) p
  join headers a on a.po = p.column_value
  left join customers b
  on b.site_use_id = coalesce(a.deliver_to_site_use_id, a.ship_to_site_use_id)
  where '123456' in (substr(a.contract_dealer,1,8), substr(a.install_dealer,1,8),
    substr(a.ordertaking_dealer,1,8));

END array_test_input;
```

With this approach the optimiser assumes the collection size is 8k, which in some circumstances can lead to a sub-optimal plan. If you know the number of members will always be significantly lower, you can add a cardinality hint to try to nudge the plan back to what you expect, giving the approximate number of POs you expect to be querying, e.g.:

```
  select /*+ cardinality(p, 10) */ b.name, ...
```

That hint is undocumented, [but it's relatively 'safe'](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2233040800346569775)...

Comment: I don't want to query all the values of the array at once, it is creating performance issue.

Comment: Why would the performance be worse with one query than with multiple queries? Is it throwing the plan out because it's defaulting to thinking there are 8k members perhaps? You could add a cardinality hint to correct that (in the second version).

Comment: Can you please explain that how to deal with it?'

Answer (score 0):

i have written my code which is very similar to your code. Below i will be posting my code step by step so that you can run in in your local and understand how you can get all the rows, but not only the last one.

**Table Creation**

```
create table tt
(
name1 varchar2(100),
address varchar2(100),
city varchar2(100),
state_code varchar2(100),
zip varchar2(100),
order_type varchar2(100),
po varchar2(100)
);
```

**Insert Script**

```
insert into tt values('nam1','address','city','state_code','zip','order_type','123');
insert into tt values('nam2','address','city','state_code','zip','order_type','789');
```

**Package Spec**

```
create or replace PACKAGE return_array_test1
AS
   ex_custom   EXCEPTION;



   TYPE return_array_test1 IS RECORD
   (
      name1 VARCHAR2 (100),
      address1 VARCHAR2 (100),
      city VARCHAR2 (100),
      state_code VARCHAR2 (100),
      zip VARCHAR2 (100),
      order_type VARCHAR2 (100) ,
      po VARCHAR2 (100)
   );

    TYPE return_array_test_TBL IS TABLE OF return_array_test1
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  type num_array is table of number; 

   PROCEDURE array_test_input  (
      po_array_in IN num_array,
      x_comp_rec  OUT return_array_test_TBL
             );
END return_array_test1;
```

**Package Body**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY return_array_test1
AS
PROCEDURE array_test_input(
    po_array_in IN num_array,
    x_comp_rec OUT return_array_test_TBL )
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. po_array_in.count
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
    SELECT a.name1,
      a.address,
      a.city,
      a.state_code,
      a.zip,
      a.order_type,
      a.po
    INTO x_comp_rec(i)
    FROM tt a
    WHERE a.po = po_array_in(i);
  END LOOP;
END array_test_input;
END return_array_test1;
```

**Calling the procedure**

```
set serveroutput on
declare
var_out return_array_test1.return_array_test_TBL;
var_in return_array_test1.num_array;
begin
var_in(1):='123';
var_in(2):='789';
return_array_test1.array_test_input(var_in,var_out);
dbms_output.put_line(var_out(1).name1);
dbms_output.put_line(var_out(2).name1);
end;
```

Hope this will make you understand.

Comment: set serveroutput on
declare
var_out return_array_test1.return_array_test_TBL;
var_in num_array := num_array(123,789);
begin


return_array_test1.array_test_input(var_in,var_out);


dbms_output.put_line('Result(s)...');
   For i IN 1 .. var_out.count
    Loop
      dbms_output.put_line(var_out(i));
    END LOOP;
  
end;

Comment: If i test the above set with num_array(123,789), it gives error

Comment: ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ARRAY_TEST_INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 13, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 13, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: In you code you have compilation issue. taken your code and corrected it. try this. SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    var_out   return_array_test1.return_array_test_tbl;
    var_in    return_array_test1.num_array := return_array_test1.num_array(123,789);
BEGIN
return_array_test1.array_test_input(
        var_in,
        var_out
    );
    dbms_output.put_line('Result(s)...');
    FOR i IN 1..var_out.count LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(var_out(i).name1 );
    END LOOP;

END;

Comment: Still gives the error:ORA-06550: line 4, column 40:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'NUM_ARRAY' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 4, column 8:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 38:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored